# Duplication of Apache Camel messages

Tags: java, apache-camel

How can I create duplicates of some Camel messages by some header condition? For example, I have a message with header `key=value1,value2,value3`, and I want to have three copies of the same messages with keys `key=value1`, `key=value2`, `key=value3`.

I tried to find some components here https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/, but haven't found any suitable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the split component of camel, then it's working.

```
from("input:queue")
    .split().method(SplitClass.class, "splitHeaders")
        .to("output:queue");

public class SplitClass{
    public List<String> splitHeaders(@Header("key") String key) {
        List<String> values = Arrays.asList(key.split(","));
        List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String value : values) {
            String message = ExchangeHelper.convertToType(exchange, String.class, exchange.getIn());
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("key", value);
            messages.add(message);
        }
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [multicast](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/multicast-eip.html)

Example code:

```
from("direct:input")
    .choice()
        .when(header("myHeader").isEqualTo("duplicate"))
            .to("direct:duplicate")
        .end()
    .to("someOtherEndpoint");

from("direct:duplicate")
    .multicast()
        .to("direct:output1")
        .to("direct:output2")
    .end();
```